# How to debug: Internal Error current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I do my first steps with GeoDjango and I am looking for better options to check faulty sql statements.

So far, I simply wanted to safe a lng+lat point in my postgresql table.

The model is defined with:

```
    geolocation = models.PointField(_('Geo Location'), 
                geography=True, 
                null = True, 
                blank = True,
                help_text=_('Geolocation with Longitude and Latitude'))

    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

In my view, I try to execute the following command

```
savedProject.geolocation = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' %(u_lng,u_lat))
```

but I receive the following error when I try to save the form:

> Exception Type:   InternalError 
>   Exception Value:   current transaction is
>   aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

**What is the reason for this error? I believe that there could be something wrong with the sql statement, but what is the best way to check? Django just provides with general error message "Internal Error".**

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In most cases this means that the **previous** SQL statement failed to execute. In this case you should:

1. **Enable SQL [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#id1)**, see the following snippet to paste in settings.py
2. **Set DEBUG=1**, or SQL won't be logged
3. **Run runserver again**, and you should see all SQL queries in the console
4. **Execute the last SQL queries directly in your database**, you should then find which queries fail and then you should be able to debug them - or open a new question which is specific to the query that causes the problem. You can use phpMyAdmin, or directly a CLI client, or whatever database client, to execute the SQL queries one by one until you find the one that needs some love.

SQL Logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = { 
   'version': 1,
   'disable_existing_loggers': True,
   'formatters': {
       'simple': {
           'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
       },  
   },  
   'handlers': {
       'console':{
           'level':'DEBUG',
           'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
           'formatter': 'simple'
       },  
   },  
   'loggers': {
       'django': {
           'handlers': ['console'],
           'level': 'DEBUG',
       },  
   }   
}
```

If this configuration does not provide any additional console output with `runserver`, then feel free to try [django-autocomplete-light's example test_project](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/demo.html):

1. Read and paste the installation commands in `/tmp`
2. Change dir to `autocomplete_light_env/src/django-autocomplete-light/test_project`
3. Open `test_project/settings.py`, replace the `LOGGING` configuration by the one above
4. Runserver and open your browser

Your console will look like:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.1, using settings 'test_project.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."name", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_content_type" WHERE ("django_content_type"."model" = taggable  AND "django_content_type"."app_label" = charfield_autocomplete ); args=('taggable', 'charfield_autocomplete')
DEBUG (0.000) 
        SELECT DISTINCT "tagging_tag".id, "tagging_tag".name
        FROM
            "tagging_tag"
            INNER JOIN "tagging_taggeditem"
                ON "tagging_tag".id = "tagging_taggeditem".tag_id
            INNER JOIN "charfield_autocomplete_taggable"
                ON "tagging_taggeditem".object_id = "charfield_autocomplete_taggable"."id"

        WHERE "tagging_taggeditem".content_type_id = 11

        GROUP BY "tagging_tag".id, "tagging_tag".name

        ORDER BY "tagging_tag".name ASC; args=[]
```

Comment: Your suggested SQL logging configuration does not provide any addition console logging for me.  I have DEBUG = True, so I'm not sure what else to try to actually see the SQL.  I had an error in my .extra() call, my where had a typo.  Took me several hours to notice it.  Would have been a piece of cake had I been able to see the SQL I was generating.  I got my issue fixed, but Django was sure no help.

Comment: I am giving +1 to your answer, because of "In most cases this means that the previous SQL statement failed to execute." was exactly the case for my issue.  The stack trace showed an object failing to save, but it was actually a query above it.  It's been my experience that Django stack traces are not helpful at all in most cases.

Comment: I'm preoccupied by "does not provide **any additional** console logging". So i updated the answer to include an easy way to test this LOGGING configuration. This allows you to know if this comes frob your project (settings?) or environment.

Comment: The important part of the logging directives (when comparing with a default Django installation) is to set `'django': {{… 'level': 'DEBUG' …}}` instead of `'INFO'` in the `loggers` section.