# PostgreSQL + GeoDjango: Better understanding how POINTS are translated

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango, geos

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am having trouble to understand how POINT references in GeoDjango are translated to query statements.

[jpic's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064018/postgresql-geodjango-what-to-do-with-internal-error) helped me very much to capture the query statements in the console, but the print out does not make any sense to me.

In my view.py function (saving the form), I have the following line:

```
savedProject.geolocation = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' %(u_lng,u_lat))
```

with u_lng and u_lat as the user coordinated (taken from the session information). u_lat and u_lng are degree values as decimals.

However when I check the sql statement as suggested, I see that the POINT was translated to

```
ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\001\001\000\000 \346\020\000\000\352\036~\243\302\256H\300\352X\245\364L\3515\300'::bytea)
```

in the sql statement and which is rejected by sql with the error message

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
```

**What is the correct way to translate lng, lat points into postgis with GeoDjango?**

Thank you for your help to understand this matter better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm far from an expert on the subject. But I've once written some code that saved a certain point in postgis database using Django.

The way I did it was:

```
model_instance.coords = Point(geo_point.latitude, geo_point.longitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error message originates from a little bug in

```
django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/adapter.py
```

Explanations for the exact problem and the patch can be found here:

- [Renooble tumblr](http://renooble.tumblr.com/post/16860675096/geodjango-is-great-but-it-contains-a-bug)
- [What the official guide did not tell](http://www.arunmozhi.in/2011/10/geodjango-what-the-official-guide-didnt-tell-me/)
- [Patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/16778/postgis-adapter-2.patch)

I have patch the four line in the adapter.py and the error is gone.

Thank you for all your help!