# Saving model form with foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

When the form is submitted, I want to save the classified instance to the `classifiedMessage` model, which is retrieved from the page slug where the form is submitted at.

forms.py

```
class ClassifiedContactForm(ModelForm):
     captcha = ReCaptchaField()
     class Meta:
          model = ClassifiedMessage
          exclude = ["classified"]
```

models.py

```
class ClassifiedMessage(models.Model):
    classified = models.ForeignKey('classified')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s"%(self.name)


class classified(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True, null=True)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=settings.SRID, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
    #objects = models.GeoManager()
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    submission_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        #return "%s %s %s"%(self.title, self.point.x, self.point.y)
        return "%s"%(self.title)
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
                return ('classified-detail', (),{'slug' :self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            slug_str = "%s %s %s %s" % (self.title, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
            self.slug = slugify(slug_str)
        if not self.point:
            location = "%s+%s+%s+%s"%(self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)
            cord = get_lat_long(location)
            x,y = cord.split(",")
            x = float(x)
            y = float(y)
            #self.point = Point(x,y)
            #self.point2 = Point(x,y)
        super(classified, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def classified_detail(request,slug):
        classifiedinst = classified.objects.get(slug=slug)
        classifiedimg = ClassifiedImage.objects.filter(classified=classifiedinst)
        '''Create a string representation of classified's address so it can be geocoded'''
        classified_address = "%s %s %s %s"%(classifiedinst.address, classifiedinst.city, classifiedinst.state, classifiedinst.zipcode)
        lat, lng = getLatLng(classified_address)
        constructed_map = getMap(lat, lng, largeMap=False)
        if request.POST:
            form = ClassifiedContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                x = form.save(commit=False)
                x.classified=classifiedinst
                x.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        else:
            form = ClassifiedContactForm(initial={'classified':classifiedinst.pk})
        return render_to_response('shclassified/classified_detail.html',
        {
            'ClassifiedContactForm':form,
            'imgObjects':classifiedimg,
            'user':request.user,
            'classified':get_object_or_404(classified,slug=slug),
            'constructed_map':constructed_map,
            },
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
        )
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.InternalError
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Postgresql Log:

```
2013-12-24 21:50:57 EST ERROR:  column "classified_id" of relation "shclassified_classifiedmessage" does not exist at character 47
2013-12-24 21:50:57 EST STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "shclassified_classifiedmessage" ("classified_id", "name", "email", "message") VALUES (5, 's', 'test@gmail.com', 'test') RETURNING "shclassified_classifiedmessage"."id"
2013-12-24 21:50:57 EST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2013-12-24 21:50:57 EST STATEMENT:  SHOW default_transaction_isolation
```

shclassified_classifiedmessage table

```
 Column  |         Type          |                                  Modifiers                                  | Storage  | Description 
---------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id      | integer               | not null default nextval('shclassified_classifiedmessage_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 name    | character varying(50) | not null                                                                    | extended | 
 email   | character varying(75) | not null                                                                    | extended | 
 message | text                  | not null                                                                    | extended | 
Indexes:
    "shclassified_classifiedmessage_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Has OIDs: no
```

Sqlreset Output:

```
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "shclassified_classifiedimage";
ALTER TABLE "shclassified_classifiedmessage" DROP CONSTRAINT "classified_id_refs_id_4e71e9af";
DROP TABLE "shclassified_classified";
DROP TABLE "shclassified_classifiedmessage";
CREATE TABLE "shclassified_classifiedmessage" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "classified_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "message" text NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "shclassified_classified" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "slug" varchar(50) UNIQUE,
    "submitted_by_id" integer REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "title" varchar(120),
    "address" varchar(120),
    "city" varchar(60),
    "state" varchar(60),
    "zipcode" varchar(5),
    "description" text,
    "submission_date" timestamp with time zone,
    "price" varchar(20)
)
;
ALTER TABLE "shclassified_classifiedmessage" ADD CONSTRAINT "classified_id_refs_id_4e71e9af" FOREIGN KEY ("classified_id") REFERENCES "shclassified_classified" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE "shclassified_classifiedimage" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "classified_id" integer REFERENCES "shclassified_classified" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "image" varchar(100)
)
;
CREATE INDEX "shclassified_classifiedmessage_classified_id" ON "shclassified_classifiedmessage" ("classified_id");
CREATE INDEX "shclassified_classified_submitted_by_id" ON "shclassified_classified" ("submitted_by_id");
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('shclassified_classified', 'point', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
CREATE INDEX "shclassified_classified_point_id" ON "shclassified_classified" USING GIST ( "point" GIST_GEOMETRY_OPS );
CREATE INDEX "shclassified_classifiedimage_classified_id" ON "shclassified_classifiedimage" ("classified_id");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064018/how-to-debug-internal-error-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-un

Comment: Your syntax b.t.w. could do with some pep8. Also consider this: `location = ' '.join(filter(None, [self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode]))` (this applies in a few places) and `x, y = map(float, cord.split(','))`.

Comment: `\d+ shclassified_classifiedmessage` please. What happens if you start out with a clean database?

Comment: Deleted all records from the table and when i try to access classifiedmessage model through Django admin it throws the same error as it does upon form submission.

Comment: Ok, but did you try: `./manage.py reset <module>`? I'm thinking you've got yourself a migration issue, where your database is not up to date with your models.

Comment: I just did it. Here is the output:Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Error: Error: shclassified couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset shclassified'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: constraint "classified_id_refs_id_4e71e9af" of relation "shclassified_classifiedmessage" does not exist

Comment: In django there is a convention of naming models with a capital first letter. This seems like a long shot, but try that. That is: `class Classified(models.Model):` Also, you might try to delete all the tables manually in the database and then do syncdb. `\dt shclassified_*` to list tables to drop.

Comment: Couldn't find any reference to said convention in the docs. It might be a good practice but not sure if it makes any difference. Regardless i ll give it a shot.

Comment: Just deleted the table via south, capitalized the model name as suggested and migrated the model and surprisingly it works :) Thanks a lot for

Comment: Actually a Python convention in general: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names